# Dependency Injection in azure function V2 with configuration file (Json/MXL)

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have worked in webapi 2 and resolved all the dependencies using unity.

All the dependencies in the application were placed in unity.config file and dependencies will be resolved with below piece of code.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration; 

var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration(section);
```

Now i have similar requirement to be implemented using Azure V2 functions.
I know it can be implemented with default DI microsoft provides or any others dependency resolver like Autofac.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmployee, EmployeeProvider.Employee>();
```

However, My specific requirement is **how the dependency can be resolved in azure V2 functions by placing dependencies in json or config files** rather than normal way of resolving 'Services.AddTransient();'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I want to make it clear, do you want to put some settings in .json file, then read it in azure function?

Comment: no the question is not reading the app settings from json file, i am looking for resolving  dependencies from json file

Comment: what should that look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can have whatever `myFile.config.json` as you want. All you need to do is just inject it from your Startup class.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     ..SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
     .AddJsonFile("app.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
     .AddEnvironmentVariables()
     .Build();
```

To access the values from the file you can use the `IConfiguration` class.

```
public MyService(IConfiguration configuration){
  var emailConfig = configuration.GetSection("Email");
  var userName = emailConfig["Username"];
}
```

**Note :** The `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` will deploy it to the portal's app settings automatically!

Comment: The question is not reading the app settings from json file, i am looking for resolving  dependencies from json file